# Excel- I need to link a cell from one worksheet into a sentence on another worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have data in worksheet1 "Calculations!" and a value in cell "M49" (which is a =sum value)
I have a sentence in worksheet2 "Approximate weight is "?" pounds."
Where "?" = the data from =Calculations!M49.

This is what I have tried but no success....

Approximate weight is "&=Calculations!M49&" pounds
Approximate weight is "& =Calculations!M49 &" pounds
Approximate weight is " & =Calculations!M49 & " pounds
Approximate weight is & =Calculations!M49 & pounds

Any Ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `="Approximate weight is "&=Calculations!M49&" pounds"`

Answer (score 0):

Scott Craner is correct but editing it to remove the equal sign in the middle of the formula: ="Approximate weight is "&Calculations!M49&" pounds"

What you're missing are the quotes ("") before and after "Approximate weight is " and " Pounds"

Take note of the spaces, they are INSIDE the quote.
anything that's not a formula or calculable should be inside a quote